# How does an AppDomain get created?

Tags: .net, winforms, winforms-interop

In .Net we can create AppDomain by writing

```
AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain");
```

My question is, How it is created internally ? Application in which we use this code that application is running in different appDomain from the new which we create so how one AppDomain create another AppDomain and how clr decide which are created in which appDomain.

Comment: Are you asking about the API used to create a nAppDomain? If so check AppDomain.CreateDomain see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6s0z09xw.aspx

Comment: @Brian: question updated, check it out.

Comment: This is a "how is babby formed" kind of question.  Simple to understand, a bazillion nasty details without any hint whatsoever how deep you want to go.  Pick up a copy of Steven Pratschner's book, check out the SSCLI20 source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite clear what you trying to resolve.

AppDomains are created by the .Net runtime when a managed application is initialised.

When you start ABC.EXE, it gets an application domain. If you start a second instance of ABC.EXE it gets a new, separate application domain.

Now, if your ABC.EXE executes `AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain");` then you'll have 4 application domains, which cannot (easily) communicate with each other.

Answer (score 0):

AppDomains are usually created by hosts. Examples of hosts are Windows Shell, ASP.NET, and IE. When you run a .NET application from the command-line, the host is the Shell. Shell creates a new AppDomain for every application. AppDomains can also be explicitly created by .NET applications